# Error in RETRO-pytorch TrainingWrapper: Error in void faiss::gpu::GpuIndexIVFPQ::verifySettings_()

Tags: python-3.x, information-retrieval

I'm encountering an error while trying to use the TrainingWrapper from the RETRO-pytorch library. This error occurs when I try to use it with larger training data but not with smaller data. I'd appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue.`

```
wrapper = TrainingWrapper(
    retro = retro,                                 # path to retro instance
    knn = 2,                                       # knn (2 in paper was sufficient)
    chunk_size = 64,                               # chunk size (64 in paper)
    documents_path = '/content/text/',              # path to folder of text
    glob = '**/*.txt',                             # text glob
    chunks_memmap_path = './train.chunks.dat',     # path to chunks
    seqs_memmap_path = './train.seq.dat',          # path to sequence data
    doc_ids_memmap_path = './train.doc_ids.dat',   # path to document ids per chunk (used for filtering neighbors belonging to same document)
    max_chunks = 500_000,                        # maximum cap to chunks
    max_seqs = 100_000,                            # maximum seqs
    knn_extra_neighbors = 100,                     # num extra neighbors to fetch
    max_index_memory_usage = '100m',
    current_memory_available = '10G'
)
```

Github repository from where i am trying:[RETRO-PYTORCH](https://github.com/lucidrains/RETRO-pytorch)
Error is as:RuntimeError: Error in void faiss::gpu::GpuIndexIVFPQ::verifySettings_() const at /project/faiss/faiss/gpu/GpuIndexIVFPQ.cu:428: Error: 'ivfpqConfig_.interleavedLayout || IVFPQ::isSupportedPQCodeLength(subQuantizers_)' failed: Number of bytes per encoded vector / sub-quantizers (256) is not supported

This error is also open issue on github repository also:[text](https://github.com/lucidrains/RETRO-pytorch/issues/24)

Code should be run :
Environment:
Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04
Python Version:  Python 3.10